# JWT Issue date vs. Expiration date check is failing due to daylight savings time. What's a year-round permanent solution?

Tags: java, datetime, time, dst

This test normally passes all year round when the there is no lost hour or gained hour to account for. But right now it's being a nuisance. We're validating that the expiration date, `getExp()`, minus 7 days,  is within 10 milliseconds of the issue date, `getIss()`. Since the `exp` and `iss` values are generated right after each other 10 milliseconds is a perfectly acceptable delta to expect the values to be between.

But now they're understandably an hour off when it looks a week into the future when the Java date code calls `setExp()` after initializing a new JWT Claim.

Assertion / test code:

```
       assertThat(claim.getExp()).isCloseTo(new DateTime(claim.getIss()).plusDays(7).toDate(), 10);
```

In english this reads: assert that the claim's expiration date is within 10 milliseconds of the claim's issue date + 7 days.

An immediate fix is to add an hour's worth of milliseconds to the allowed delta but I was curious to see if there was a better solution.

EDIT: I believe I found the issue. We initialize claim issue date and claim expiration date using ZonedDateTime.now():

```
Claim claim = new Claim();
claim.setIss(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant())); 
claim.setExp(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).plusDays(7).toInstant()));
```

But when we validate with JODA time we assume our local rules for daylight savings time. This obviously causes an issue with GMT DST vs. American DST rules.

EDIT2: The fix involved 2 words and updating the unit test to respect UTC:

```
    assertThat(claim.getExp()).isCloseTo(new DateTime(claim.getIss(), DateTimeZone.UTC).plusDays(7).toDate(), 10);
```

Comment: How are the values generated? What type are they? E.g. are you using Joda-Time? How are they stored?

Comment: I added the implementation code but it's not Joda specific even though I am using it. The assertion expects the expiration of the JWT to be very close to 7 days after the issue date. This passes all year round until date libraries look 7 days ahead into the future and drop an hour as a result of daylight savings time calculations and the lost hour.

Comment: 1) Since the two date values are both based on `now`, why would you expect a 10 ms discrepancy to occur? `exp` and `iss` are *exactly* 7 days apart, as determined by the `DateTime` class. --- 2) Since the calculation done in the `assertThat` is *exactly* the same calculation done when the values were created, it should never fail. Only reason it could fail is that they are running in different locales that don't agree on DST.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I made incorrect assumptions about the origin of the JWT Issue / Expiration date generation which I will remove. It looks like there's a DST disagreement issue between our JWT library `io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts` where the issue / expiration values are set and the Joda Time library where the differences are calculated.

Comment: By the way, there’s no point in using `ZonedDateTime` for UTC. Just use `Instant`, always in UTC by definition: `Instant.now().plus( 7 , ChronoUnit.DAYS )`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Basil that's very helpful - I'll refactor my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only two solutions are:

1. Change your reporting so that, instead of being based on local time, is uses UTC (ie, epoch unix time). This is the preferable solution from a tech point of view since it's a worldwide standard including most shared servers and data sources; no DST to worry about; and you can still have your reports calculate local time.
2. Alternatively, to find or add a reliable 'dateadd'-type function that take Daylight Savings into account.

I've always been surprised that all platforms don't have that functionality built-in.  Granted, DST has a confusing, ever-evolving set of rules that are region-specific (by continent, country, and is some areas by "state" or even "county") ...but still.

Currently, in most of North America, DST:

- **Begins** on the 2nd Sunday of March. ("Spring Forward" so clocks change from 01:59 to 03:00)
- **Ends** on the 1st Sunday of November. ("Fall Back" from 01:59 to 01:00)

Windows API has functionality for calculating whether DST is in effect but really, no application should allow an application to display, for example in North America: "Sunday March 11, 2018 02:30:00" because *that time doesn't exist*.

...still, #1 is your preferable solution because accuracy and standardization are more straightforward.

Comment: I would've added some links and more info but I'm on my cell; i'll check back later on

Comment: No worries I thought this was an issue with jwt.util bit I believe the underlying issue is that we initialize claim.exp() and claim.iss() in UTC but then verify it in local time. Since there's no DST in UTC during March, that's our issue.

Comment: Yup fixed it - one line fix. The unit test just needed `new DateTime(claim.getIss(), DateTimeZone.UTC)`